# decrease the download size of an product image

Tags: magento, product

you can use inspect element to see product image source and download the images .

the sizes of image are more than 400 kb.

I want to reduce the size of the image.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance

decrease the download size of an product image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following link to compress product image.

http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/

In that first you need to choose and upload product image. Then it will give you compressed image with less size. Use that image to set for product image in backend.